# drawing .tmx tiled map inside canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tiled

Is there any function in javascript that can read a .tmx image file and draw it inside an html5 canvas using the default drawing funcion of images inside the canvas `context.drawImage(img,x,y,cw,ch)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, [TMX file format](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) are not directly supported in JavaScript so you'll have to write a parser for it.

The following page describes how to parse a TMX file (I cannot paste any content from that page due to size and copyright/license). The code is for ActionScript, an ECMA-script cousin of JavaScript, so the code itself is not so hard to port:

**[Parse TMX files](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-and-rendering-tiled-tmx-format-maps-in-your-own-game-engine--gamedev-3104)**

As to load and parse the XML itself: JavaScript has a built in XML parser, the `XMLHttpRequest` object, which you load the file with, combined with the `DOMParser`, see this answer for how:

**[Parse XML with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204165/using-javascript-to-parse-an-xml-file)**

If you don't want to write it yourselves you can take a look at for example the [GameJS](http://gamejs.org/) library which has a built-in [*TMX parser*](https://github.com/GameJs/gamejs/blob/master/src/gamejs/tiledmap.js). The library is MIT licensed so you are free to use its code or part of its code in your own project(s).

After the file has been parsed you also need to have code to put the tiles on the canvas. A simple 2D tile engine is easy to make. You can use for example this as a starting point (it's not JavaScript but the code is easy to read and to port):

**[A simple 2D tile engine](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-creating-a-tile-map-engine--gamedev-10900)**

Comment: i can include the tmx.js in my project and use it to load my tilemap in my canvas ?

Comment: @Sora you should be able to do that, at least that's how I interpret the "modify and merge" part, but then again I'm not a lawyer don't take anything I say for absolute :) The MIT license require you to include the original copyright header as in this case. I would recommend though isolating it from your own project if you use a different license (you can still minify and merge later). But check on the net for resources on this topic.