# Display isometric tiles correctly with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, tile

I want to create a simple isometric tilemap with HTML and CSS.

The tiles are 128px wide and 64px high, but some of them, like the one below, contains graphical elements that gives them a total height of 128px.

[image: tile with grass]
[image: tile with a bush]

In this simplified example, the isometric tilemap is only 2x2 tiles and should look like this:

[image]

How do I display these tiles correctly with HTML and CSS, so that they have the right placement and proportions?

Please note that the 2x2 tilemap is just an example. The solution needs to work just as well (or just about) if the map is 5x5 tiles or 25x75 tiles. It also needs to work regardless of tile order.

So far, my idea has been to rotate the container to make it isometric, and then rotate the tiles in the opposite direction to "compensate" for the rotation of the container (I'd prefer to display the tiles the way they are drawn). But I'm not sure this is the right approach. The placement is not correct and the images are distorted.

[image: result]

Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.container {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: blue;
}

.tile {
  width: 128px;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.grass {
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/39MxJ.png");
}

.bush {
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpNEI.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
  <div class="tile bush"></div>
  <div class="tile bush"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you positioning with respect to `128px` `height` but as tiles are only `64px` this may help in improve positioning

Comment: @Rana I'm not sure where you got that image, but I just changed the snippet to use the images mentioned in the post itself, and that matches the outcome posted.

Comment: Whay about going the Canvas way? Beside you could go the tmx way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349883/drawing-tmx-tiled-map-inside-canvas-in-html5

Comment: @HereticMonkey how you managed to get the images , as I am not able to do that in the answer below

Comment: I just [edit]ed the question and copied the URL from the references at the bottom of the question (next to `[1]:` and `[2]:`).

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you tell why images are showing in answer below and can you correct it plz

Comment: @Rana I don't know why exactly. I think you've rotated or translated them out of sight.

Comment: @HereticMonkey by mistake I removed the `width` property of `.tile` . That's the reason  for not showing images

Comment: @aloisdg: Do you think the canvas way would provide for a better solution? If possible, I'd prefer use 'vanilla code' to keep the code as light-weight and to the point as possible. I already have a tmx file of the map, but as I said I would prefer to write the code on my own to suite my particular needs. Btw, I've added a paragraph to my question: "Please note that the 2x2 tilemap is just an example. The solution needs to work just as well (or just about) if the map is 5x5 tiles or 25x75 tiles. It also needs to work regardless of how the tiles are positioned within the map."

Comment: You will end up with your own homemade library. The complexity will be here but you have to deal with it.

Comment: I'm not making a game, though, just a map. If I can find a solution to this issue that would go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

With the current structure, just change some CSS properties.

I don't think there is any need to use the "transform" property, this can be achieved by the `display: grid` property also.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(128px, 1fr));
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  width: 258px;
  grid-auto-rows: 32px;
  min-height: 140px;
}

.tile {
  width: 128px;
  height: 87px;
}

.tile:first-child,
.bush:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  width: 100%;
}

.grass {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/39MxJ.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}

.bush {
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpNEI.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  margin-top: -52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
   <div class="tile bush"></div>
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
  <div class="tile bush"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the working example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/iampankajdhiman/pen/OJgeOZa)

Comment: Thank you. This looks very nice. Unfortunately, your solution is tailor-made for this particular layout, with 2 grass tiles and 2 bush tiles. I'm looking for a solution that works just as well (or just about) if the map is 5x5 tiles or 25x75 tiles. It also needs to work regardless of how the tiles (grass, bush etc) are positioned within the map. I'm sorry for not being clear about this in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reposition each tile separately with a hit and trial method like in below snippet:
Below snippet is for demo only you can reposition according to need and wherever you want in blue are

```css
.container {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: blue;
}

.tile {
  width: 128px;
}
.tile:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(64px) translateY(64px) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.tile:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(42px) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.tile:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(16px) translateY(-18px) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.tile:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(-45px) translateY(-42px) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.grass {
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/39MxJ.png");
}

.bush {
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpNEI.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
  <div class="tile grass"></div>
  <div class="tile bush"></div>
  <div class="tile bush"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only see the blue tile in this example

Comment: @JoshuaSwain by mistake I removed the `width` property of `.tile` . That's the reason for not showing images

Comment: Thank you Rana, but I'm afraid the result doesn't look exactly right when I run the code snippet. It looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/SAAygVB.png If possible, I would like to be able to render all tiles the same way regardless of their position in the map (or at least all tiles of the same type). If the map is 100x100 tiles, the CSS will be very lenghty if you have to format them individually.

Comment: @Candleout It is for demo only . I only attached them to show how to do make a square tile. You can reposition according to need . Instead you can use the grid as shown in above answer

Comment: I'm looking for a more flexible/general solution, that can deal with any number of tiles (10x10, 10x75, etc) as well as tile arrangements. It's OK to have separate CSS rules for differens tile types (grass, bush, etc), but I find it unpractical to have to deal with every single tile/position individually. I have added a comment about this in my question and in a comment to the above answer. Sorry for not making i clear from the start.