# How to filter/search on xml data loaded in html table?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am new to JavaScript and programming in general.

So I am wokring on dummy data from XML file to create a chromosome gene browser.

What I am trying to do is to have XML data uploaded in a table, which works. Now I would like to implement something which would allow me to filter/search on it "live" by any values of all columns but I can't seem to get it work. Can anyone help?

This is my dummy **cd_catalog.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <GENE>
  <GENEIDENTIFIERS>
    <ACCESSION>Empire Burlesque</ACCESSION>
    <GENID>Bob Dylan</GENID>
    <PRODUCT>USA</PRODUCT>
    <LOCATION>Columbia</LOCATION>
    <DETAILS>10.90</DETAILS>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </GENEIDENTIFIERS>
  <GENEIDENTIFIERS>
    <ACCESSION>Hide your heart</ACCESSION>
    <GENID>Bonnie Tyler</GENID>
    <PRODUCT>UK</PRODUCT>
    <LOCATION>CBS Records</LOCATION>
    <DETAILS>9.90</DETAILS>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </GENEIDENTIFIERS>
  <GENEIDENTIFIERS>
    <ACCESSION>Greatest Hits</ACCESSION>
    <GENID>Dolly Parton</GENID>
    <PRODUCT>USA</PRODUCT>
    <LOCATION>RCA</LOCATION>
    <DETAILS>9.90</DETAILS>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </GENEIDENTIFIERS>
</GENE>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>Chromosome Browser</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for genes..." title="Type in a accession no., gene ID, product or location">



<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Display genes</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Accession</th><th>Gene ID</th><th>Protein Product(s)</th></th><th>Loction</th><th>Details</h></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GENEIDENTIFIERS");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ACCESSION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("GENID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("LOCATION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("DETAILS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to parse the XML with a DOM parser, you can find a well done explanation here:

[Using JavaScript to parse an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204165/using-javascript-to-parse-an-xml-file)

And if you want to know in more detail how DOM parsing works:

[DOMParser - MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Are you suggesting that current script to present XML in a table is not gonna work with filtering the table contents?